# Cordova ionic plugin for normal cordova?

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I found an good plugin for cropping images which I want to add to my cordova app.

The Plugin: https://github.com/JrSchild/jr-crop

As the title says, it's for ionic. I don't know much about ionic just that it is something like a framework to build Apps. I don't use it just 'normal' cordova so is it possible to use this Plugin also?
What do I have to do?

Hope there is a solution

Number987

Comment: Did you follow the instructions? What is exactly your question?

Comment: I am not using Ionic Framework, i am just programming in Cordova. So the plugin instruction says that its an ionic plugin but i want to use it for my normal Cordova (without a framework(without ionic)). How can I do this? Or is this even possible? :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does depend on Ionic (version 1.1.1 according to `bower.json`), so there's no way you can use it with vanilla Cordova.

Yo could reuse some of the code to implement your own image cropper, it's only 300 lines of js. It will be easier if you already use Angular 1 in your app.

Comment: Ok thanks for the answer. If I am understanding you right, thers is no solution, the only possibility is to change the code by yourself?

Comment: Unfortunately yes. The image transformation is done in pure js functions, so you can at least copy that as a starting point.

Comment: Ok. Unfortunately i am not a good programmer and when I looked in the code it doesnt make lots of sense to me :/ Is there anyone who is able to to this? That would be wonderful ;))